# Generic Keyboard Driver for Linux

Tags: linux, kernel, driver, hid, keylogger

I'm trying to write a Linux keyboard driver that matches to any keyboard entering the system.

After the driver is connected with the device, I want to intercept the input, log it somewhere, then forward it to the system, so that it is actually displayed on the user's screen.

So far, I have tried copying a driver directly from the linux source code.I have tried both usbkbd and usbhid drivers, I managed to get them to probe a device (using its Vendor and Product ID), but I did not manage to receive any scancodes. No keys are being typed out when my driver matches (even if I copied and pasted the source code from linux).

These are the sources I tried:

usbkbd:
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/hid/usbhid/usbkbd.c

usbhid (did not manage to get it to compile):
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/hid/usbhid/hid-core.c

Any tips on how I should proceed?

Comment: That's the source of the Linux kernel. I'm pretty sure it works, but it has a rather specific build process. You should also be somewhat more specific in your question.

Comment: Please read about [mcve] . In a nut shell, reader's need something they can copy/paste into their local environment and get the same errors you are getting. Use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu to format as `code/data/output/errMsgs`. Good luck.